# problem on dual boot ubuntu 14.04.1 alongside windows 7

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, uefi, mbr, gpt

I have lenovo e530(core i5). when I want to install ubuntu alongside windows 7(ultimate), in the menu i select install alongside, the continue change to restart to continue and when I press it, my e530 restart and nothing happening and again i see the boot page of ubuntu.
i download ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso and with universal usb installer make a boot-able flash disk.
I read many forum. also my windows is not in uefi and it is legacy bios. even I disable quick boot to another option. also my partiotion is not GPT and it is MBR.
I try ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso and the same thing happened.
please help me

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try one-time boot from your USB drive, there is an specific key to get to the one-time boot options (most of the times it's F12) select 'Install Alongside Windows' and restart. Your laptop should boot into Windows 7 normally, don't disconnect the USB. A new window will be shown to you to install Ubuntu.